# Fetching a variable from a vbscript array

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have these variables

```vb
STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_208="test"   
STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_209=""    
STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_210=""    
STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_211=""    
STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_212=""    
STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_213=""    
STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_214=""    
STATE_verifmoduleid="208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214"
```

So i would like to fetch the variable which is not empty based on the list/array

In my example, `STATE_verifmoduleid` contains the following:

```vb
STATE_verifmoduleid="208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214"
```

So basically, I should catch only `STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_208="test"` because it's not empty.

I wrote this code but it's not returning the value `"TEST"` contained in the variable `STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_208="test"`

```vb
Dim STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_(1000)
Dim verifmoduleid

'Here the code of the form/request.form, bla bla bla which is working ...

Dim CheckVerifyModulesIDs,CheckVerifyModulesID, Citems

CheckVerifyModulesIDs = replace(STATE_verifmoduleid," ","")
CheckVerifyModulesID = Split(CheckVerifyModulesIDs,",")

For each Citems in CheckVerifyModulesID
    if (STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_(Citems)) <> "" then
        response.write (STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_(Citems)) & "<br>"
    end if
next
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm waaaay to out of practice with old-school asp/vbscript to be much help, but I do know you can fix this kind of thing by writing out debugging messages with the actual value of the variables. At some point, you'll find one was different than you expected, and then you'll be able to reason about the code to think back to why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the variables `STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_*` are declared separately, so you need to build each variable name dynamically as a string and evaluate that string as expression.

```vb
STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_208 = "test"   
STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_209 = ""    
STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_210 = ""    
STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_211 = ""    
STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_212 = ""    
STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_213 = ""    
STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_214 = ""    
STATE_verifmoduleid = "208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214"

' Here the code of the form/request.form, bla bla bla which is working ...

ids  =  Split(Replace(STATE_verifmoduleid," ",""),",")

For Each id in ids
    v = Eval("STATE_Newverifdetaillibelle_" & id)
    If v <> "" then
        Response.Write v & "<br>"
    End If
Next
```

Another way is to put all values to an array or a dictionary, then there is no need to use `Eval`.